# Android : service not being launched after app restart

Tags: android

I am facing something I don't understand at all and it might come from the fact that I am quite new to Android.

I launch a simple activity that creates a service. No magic here. Everything works fine when I launch the app. But if I kill it and start it within a few seconds again, my service doesn't get launched (I added a log on the OnCreate() method of my service, and nothing gets displayed).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "ON CREATE");
    s_instance = this;

    registerReceiver(deviceEventReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.horizon.watch.moto360.receiveDeviceEvent"));

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Launch default home page
    defaultHomePage = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.defaulthomepage);
    defaultHomePage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    startService(new Intent(this, WearMessageListenerService.class));

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "ON DESTROY");

    stopService(new Intent(this, WearMessageListenerService.class));
    unregisterReceiver(deviceEventReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Is your service listed in the manifest file?

Comment: Yes it is. It's so weird, it's like if I wasn't destroying the service in time and it wouldn't be able to be recreated when I relaunch the app fast enough

Comment: Before u start the service check to C if the service is running

Comment: Did you use START_STICKY? remove stopService from ondestroy

Comment: I didn't use START_STICKY, and why should I remove stopService from onDestroy()? How do I kill it then?

Comment: @orignMaster you are right, my service is still running when I relaunch fast. It means it wasn't killed fast enough I guess?

Answer (score 1):

Your service is likely not starting because it is already running, due to `onDestroy()` not being called.

From the onDestroy() docs:

> Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving
>   data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content
>   provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here. This method is usually
>   implemented to free resources like threads that are associated with an
>   activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things
>   around while the rest of its application is still running. **There are
>   situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting
>   process without calling this method** (or any others) in it, so it
>   should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around
>   after the process goes away.

Also, you say you "kill" your app. I would assume you mean you use the task manager to close the app. This is likely the cause of why your `onDestroy()` is not getting called, and so your original service is likely not being stopped (as mentioned in the comments on your question). The `onDestroy()` method is only really guaranteed to get called if `finish()` is called on your app. You can test for this.

In your `onPause()` method, you can call [`isFinishing()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing())to test whether your app is just pausing, or if it is actually finishing all the way. If it is actually finishing, you can put your `stopService()` call there to actually stop the service.

---

**EDIT: In response to comments below...**
This is how you would implement the `onPause()` method as described above...

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(isFinishing()) {
        Log.d("APP SHUTTING DOWN", "The app is shutting down and the service should be stopped.");
        stopService(new Intent(this, WearMessageListenerService.class)); 
        unregisterReceiver(deviceEventReceiver);
    } else {
        Log.d("APP PAUSING", "The app has moved to the background, but is still active. The service should continue running.");
    }
}
```

Comment: When I look at the logs, onDestroy() always gets called. But the onDestroy() of the service gets called few seconds later. Which means if I restart the app fast enough, the onDestroy() in the service doesn't get called

Comment: @krakig - Right, which is why your service is still running when you restart the app. The `onDestroy()` method is not a good place to do clean up code, as it's unpredictable in this way. There are a bunch of other threads and processes that the system is finishing at the same time, and so you can run into timing issues like this. That is why Google officially recommends the way I mention above in their docs. You should call your `stopService` in `onPause()` and test for `isFinishing()`.

Comment: The matter is that I'd like to keep it alive when the screen is locked for example (and the activity triggers the onPause() then, so it would mean my service wouldn't be able to receive the events)

Comment: @krakig - No, that is incorrect. When your app moves away from the foreground, `onPause()` is called, but since you have `if(isFinishing())` in this method, it will only stop your service if the app is shutting down. But if your app is simply in a dormant state (such as when the screen is locked), this code would not be executed and your service would continue to run.

Comment: I added some code in my answer to demonstrate how to implement this.

Comment: I tried your solution but I am having the same result : if I restart the app too fast, service is still running